# JQuery Append only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to load a custom form submisson error box in Facebox, when testing around with some code im having trouble getting .append() to append more than one time. If both of the example errors are failed its only loading appending and loading one in to the facebox, but if one at a time is failed it will show the correct one that is supposed to display, just not both at once..

Sorry if the code is messy / not efficient, javascript isn't my strong suit.

```
  $('#signup').submit( function() {
 var fname = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();
 var uname = $("#username").val();
 var pass = $("#password").val();
 var passc = $("#passwordc").val();
 var email = $("#email").val();                   

 if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/.test(uname) == false) {
           //alert('Usernames can be alphanumeric but may include an underscore.');
       $("#errorholder").append('<tr><td style="margin: 0;">Usernames can be alphanumeric but may include a underscore.</td></tr>');
 }
 else if(/^[a-zA-Z']*$/.test(fname) == false) {
      //alert('First name may not contain numbers or symbols.');
      $("#errorholder").append('<tr><td style="margin: 0;">First name may not contain numbers or symbols</td></tr>');
 }
 else if(/^[a-zA-Z']*$/.test(lname) == false) {
      //alert('Last name may not contain numbers or symbols.');
 }
 else if(!$("#fname").val()){
      //alert('First name required');
 }
 else if(!lname){
      //alert('Last name required');
 }
 else if(!uname){
      //alert('Userame required');
 }
 else if(pass!=passc){
      //alert('Passwords don\'t match');
 }
 else if(pass.length<5){
      //alert('Password must be at least 5 characters.');
 }
 else if(!email){
      //alert('Email required');
 }  
 else if (!$("input:radio[name='gender']:checked").val()) {
          // alert('Please select gender.');
 }
 jQuery.facebox({ div: '#piksplay' });
 return false;

  });
});
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle

Comment: You're using `else if`, so if the first if statement is true, i.e. if there is an error, none of the other `else if` statements will be executed, as they are only there "if else"! You need to change it to a series of `if` statements if you like to check for all the conditions in series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to test multiple conditions, but you're using `else if`. As soon as your code find a `true` condition then it doesn't test anything else, so only one `append` will get fired each time. These all need to be separate `if` statements.

Comment: Wow, i've been up too long. Thank You, Ian and Adeneo.

Comment: It's 4:23am here. Maybe you just haven't been up long enough! :)